# convert a number to a string without expanding the type

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm using react native and the `fontWeight` style value on text accepts the following:

`fontWeight?: "normal" | "bold" | "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "600" | "700" | "800" | "900";`

I have a 3rd party API that returns the fontWeight as a number. This API will return the following for fontWeight:

`100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900`

I'm trying to connect the two but can't seem to figure it out. Doing

`fontWeight: APIResult.fontWeight.toString(),` raises an error as at that point I'm passing a `string` in when react native is expecting an exact value.

Comment: Are you sure that `APIResult.fontWeight.toString()` will be one of `"normal" | "bold" | "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "600" | "700" | "800" | "900"`?  Or is it possible that it won't be?

Comment: I edited my question, the API returns `100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900`

Comment: Could you paste the stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about parsing from one format to another? It will looks like this:

```js
type S = "normal" | "bold" | "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500" | "600" | "700" | "800" | "900";
type N = 100 | 200 | 300 | 400 | 500 | 600 | 700 | 800 | 900;

type ParseFontWeightToString<T extends N> =
  T extends 100 ? '100' :
  T extends 200 ? '200' :
  T extends 300 ? '300' :
  T extends 400 ? '400' :
  T extends 500 ? '500' :
  T extends 600 ? '600' :
  T extends 700 ? '700' :
  T extends 800 ? '800' :
  T extends 900 ? '900' :
  never

type R = ParseFontWeightToString<700> // "700"
type R1 = ParseFontWeightToString<750> // ERROR
```

It's not beautiful code hoverer you will declare it only once.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20S%20%3D%20%22normal%22%20%7C%20%22bold%22%20%7C%20%22100%22%20%7C%20%22200%22%20%7C%20%22300%22%20%7C%20%22400%22%20%7C%20%22500%22%20%7C%20%22600%22%20%7C%20%22700%22%20%7C%20%22800%22%20%7C%20%22900%22%3B%0Atype%20N%20%3D%20100%20%7C%20200%20%7C%20300%20%7C%20400%20%7C%20500%20%7C%20600%20%7C%20700%20%7C%20800%20%7C%20900%3B%0A%0Atype%20ParseFontWeightToString%3CT%20extends%20N%3E%20%3D%0A%20%20T%20extends%20100%20%3F%20'100'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20200%20%3F%20'200'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20300%20%3F%20'300'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20400%20%3F%20'400'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20500%20%3F%20'500'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20600%20%3F%20'600'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20700%20%3F%20'700'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20800%20%3F%20'800'%20%3A%0A%20%20T%20extends%20900%20%3F%20'900'%20%3A%0A%20%20never%0A%0Atype%20R%20%3D%20ParseFontWeightToString%3C700%3E%20%2F%2F%20%22700%22)

Answer (score 0):

The *simplest* (but not type-safe) solution is just to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions)

```
type FontWeightAPIString = "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | "500" |
  "600" | "700" | "800" | "900";

{ fontWeight: APIResult.fontWeight.toString() as FontWeightAPIString }
```

or the even simpler (but even less safe)

```
{ fontWeight: APIResult.fontWeight.toString() as any }
```

---

Another possible solution, if you want to try to help the compiler understand the implications of calling `toString()`:

```
interface WeightMap {
    100: "100";
    200: "200";
    300: "300";
    400: "400";
    500: "500";
    600: "600";
    700: "700";
    800: "800";
    900: "900";
}
type WeightNumber<N extends keyof WeightMap = keyof WeightMap> = 
  { toString(this: number): WeightMap[N] } & N;

interface APIResult {
    fontWeight: WeightNumber; // was originally just 100 | 200 | ... | 800 | 900 ?
}

interface MyStyle {
    fontWeight?: "normal" | "bold" | "100" | "200" | "300" | "400" | 
      "500" | "600" | "700" | "800" | "900";
}

declare const apiResult: APIResult;
const foo: MyStyle = {
    fontWeight: apiResult.fontWeight.toString() // no error now
}
```

Here we've represented the mapping from numeric weights to string weights as `WeightMap`, and have a new type alias called `WeightNumber` which is a subtype of `number`.  A `WeightNumber` is known to be the relevant union of numeric literals (`100 | 200 | ... | 800 | 900`), and it's got an explict `toString()` method which returns the relevant union of string literals (`"100" | "200" | ... | "800" | "900"`).  You can also get a more specific type like `WeightNumber<200>` if you want.

Then, we declare that `APIResult['fontWeight']` is a `WeightNumber`.

This allows the compiler to infer that the return type of `APIResult['fontWeight']['toString']` conforms to the `fontWeight` style and you have no errors.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!